# Woocommerce subscription plugin, downgrade or upgrade function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggling now for a couple of days and can't find a good documentation or examples across the internet. I have the following situation:

Users can switch their subscription for next week.
They can choose how many meals they want based on the subscription of a variable product. 
So one product contains more variantion products based on the woocommerce subscription plugin.

So they can choose from 1 to 14 meals a week. The change they make on the subscription has to start the week after they made change on the subscription .

What is the best way to update the users subscription. I can't find the right function for this. 
I hope somebody can give me a push in the right direction :).

I found a way to remove the order and replace this with the new one but i think it's not the right way.

```
    subscription = wcs_get_subscription($subid);
    $subscription->remove_order_items('line_item');
    $productnew = wc_get_product($id);
    $subscription->add_product($productnew,'1', $args);
```